# How to keep the original class/format when Transpose dataframe R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `NumOrder1` contains 5 columns as followings:

```
     ChannelN Order1 Order2 Order3 Order4 Order5
1     EXS     256     242    251     270    274
2     ISO     25      29     26      43    26
3     ISS     89      74     111     85    79
```

Now I use transpose`NumbOrder2<-data.frame(t(NumOrder1))`to convert the matrix's columns and rows. Now I have

```
            X1    X2   X3   
ChannelN    EXS   ISO  ISS 
Order1      256   25   89                                
Order2      242   29   74                             
Order3      251   26   111                       
Order4      270   43   85                             
Order5      274   26   79
```

Then I use following code to remove the column names and replace by the first row value:

```
colnames(NumbOrder2)<-NumbOrder1[,1]
NumbOrder3<-data.frame(NumbOrder2[-1,])
```

Now I get the right table NumbOrder3

```
ChannelN    EXS   ISO  ISS 
Order1      256   25   89                                
Order2      242   29   74                             
Order3      251   26   111                       
Order4      270   43   85                             
Order5      274   26   79
```

But the problem is: The class of column in original data frame was `integer` But now it is `factor`.I am not able to plot any chart with this new data frame.I try to convert with as.integer, but does not help.

Any solutions to keep the format of my original data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is that transposing `t` turnes the data.frame into a matix. A matrix can only hold values on one single class. As you have factor and integer in your `data.frame` the integers are saved as factors within the matrix.

To get what you want first set the rownames (the colnames of *NumOrder2*), remove the factor-column and then transpose

```
rownames(NumOrder1) <- NumOrder1$ChannelN
NumOrder1 <- NumOrder1[,-1]
NumOrder2 <- as.data.frame(t(NumOrder1))
```

Check if they are integers:

```
> lapply(NumOrder2,class)
$EXS
[1] "integer"

$ISO
[1] "integer"

$ISS
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps me understand the t() more!

Comment: I wonder if really need the `NumOrder1 <- NumOrder1[,-1]` step, can't you just `as.data.frame(t(NumOrder1[-1]))`?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I made this extra step for an easier understanding. Also indexing `[,-1]` instead of (the shorter version) `[-1]`

Comment: Thank you!  This answer was helpful to me, since I wished to number-format some numbers in an Excel sheet, but transposing caused some mixed-type columns, and the transposed sheets appeared with an attractive little green triangle, indicating the numbers had been imported as TEXT.  Setting the rownames, then eliminating the text from the source dataframe before transposition ... perfect!  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `mapply`

```
x <- "ChannelN    EXS   ISO  ISS 
Order1      256   25   89                                
Order2      242   29   74                             
Order3      251   26   111                       
Order4      270   43   85                             
Order5      274   26   79"
df <- read.table(text=x, header=T)
df$EXS <- mapply(as.integer, df$EXS)
df$ISO <- mapply(as.integer, df$ISO)
df$ISS <- mapply(as.integer, df$ISS)
df
#   ChannelN EXS ISO ISS
# 1   Order1 256  25  89
# 2   Order2 242  29  74
# 3   Order3 251  26 111
# 4   Order4 270  43  85
# 5   Order5 274  26  79
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do this with `recast` from `library(reshape2)`

```
library(reshape2)
res <- recast(df1, variable~ChannelN, value.var='value')
res
#  variable EXS ISO ISS
#1   Order1 256  25  89
#2   Order2 242  29  74
#3   Order3 251  26 111
#4   Order4 270  43  85
#5   Order5 274  26  79

str(res)
#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
#$ variable: Factor w/ 5 levels "Order1","Order2",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#$ EXS     : int  256 242 251 270 274
#$ ISO     : int  25 29 26 43 26
#$ ISS     : int  89 74 111 85 79
```